# DataGridView with ODBC data adapter

Tags: vb.net

I am load data from database to my datagridview through ODBC adapter.

```
        cmd = New Odbc.OdbcCommand(sql, cn)
        adp = New Odbc.OdbcDataAdapter(cmd)
        adp.Fill(ds, "temp2")

        bs.DataSource = ds
        DataGridView2.DataSource = bs
```

That way I can change and update data in database "lively".
But I have different situation now.
For changing data I have to go on grid's doubleclick to another form and when I come back I would like that my datagridview show changes in certain row.

This is what I try:

```
    Dim fl As New dataform
    With fl
        .StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual
        .aCallerLocation = Me.Location
        .ShowDialog()
    End With
    fl = Nothing

    Dim c_builder As New Odbc.OdbcCommandBuilder(adp)
    Dim o As Integer
    Try
        o = adp.Update(ds, "temp2")
        MsgBox(o)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

But I can't simply get it whole day! There is no exception generated but "o" is allways zero.

What do I do wrong and how to get this functionality to see changes in the row after returnimg from "dataform"?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
cmd = New Odbc.OdbcCommand(sql, cn)
adp = New Odbc.OdbcDataAdapter(cmd)
Dim c_builder As New Odbc.OdbcCommandBuilder(adp)
adp.Fill(ds, "temp2")

bs.DataSource = ds
DataGridView2.DataSource = bs
```

and this

```
Private Sub btnSave_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click

    Dim dsChange As DataSet = New DataSet
    'add record
    If (ds.HasChanges(DataRowState.Added)) Then            
        dsChange = ds.GetChanges(DataRowState.Added)
        Dim rowchange As Integer
        rowchange = adp.Update(dsChange, "temp2")
        If (rowchange > 0) Then
            MessageBox.Show(rowchange.ToString() & " Record Berhasil Dimasukan")
        End If
    End If

    'Modified record
    If (ds.HasChanges(DataRowState.Modified)) Then            
        dsChange = ds.GetChanges(DataRowState.Modified)
        Dim rowchange As Integer
        rowchange = adp.Update(dsChange, "temp2")
        If (rowchange > 0) Then
            MessageBox.Show(rowchange.ToString() & " Record Berhasil Dihapus")
        End If
    End If

    'Delete record
    If (ds.HasChanges(DataRowState.Deleted)) Then            
        dsChange = ds.GetChanges(DataRowState.Deleted)
        Dim rowchange As Integer
        rowchange = adp.Update(dsChange, "temp2")
        If (rowchange > 0) Then
            MessageBox.Show(rowchange.ToString() & " Record Berhasil Diubah")
        End If
    End If

    'Menerapkan perubahan
    ds.AcceptChanges()

    'Refresh(DataGrid)
    DataGridView2.Refresh()

End Sub
```